# How to disable Customized UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I subclassed `UIButton` and did some customized drawing in `drawRect` method such as drawing `NSAttributedString` and `UIImage`.

However, after I did this, the customized `UIButton` doesn't gray out when `enabled` is set to `NO`. I think my customized drawing happens on top of its state. How do I deal with this?

Sharing my drawing code here:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    if (self.faceUp) {
        [self drawCardText:self.card.contents inRect:self.bounds];
    } else {
        [self drawCardImage:[UIImage imageNamed:CardBackImageName] inRect:self.bounds];
    }
}

- (void)drawCardText:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // set background color to white so text can be shown
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] fill];

    UIFont *preferedFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    UIFont *actualFont = [UIFont fontWithName:preferedFont.fontName
                                     size:hypotf(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 6.0];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: actualFont};

    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
    [self setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)drawCardImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 1.0f);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *actualImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:actualImage] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] fill];
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your code

Comment: I'd add a check whether the button is disabled on drawRect: and instead of drawing normally draw gray things there.

Comment: I am not sure if `setNeedsDisplay` is implemented in the setter for `enabled`. Otherwise, when I set `enabled` to `NO`, how does it know to redraw?

Comment: @bohanl See my answer, may be it will help you.

Comment: @bohanl override setEnabled and call setNeedsDisplay there, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to add an overlay view with grey color and some alpha yourself. Remove the overlay when button is enabled again.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this method to CustomButton class.

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled{

    //disableLayer.hidden = !enabled;
    if (enabled) {
        //self.enabled = YES;
        self.alpha = 1.0;
    }else{
        //self.enabled = NO;
        self.alpha = 0.7;
    }
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
}
```

For enable or disable call-

```
[customButtob setEnabled:buttonStatus];
```

If you want to change color, add a background layer, and toggle its hidden property in setEnabled method.

```
disableLayer = [CALayer layer];
disableLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:20/255.0f green:20/255.0f blue:20/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
disableLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
disableLayer.hidden = YES;
[self.layer insertSublayer:disableLayer below:otherLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 btn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Or you can use

```
btn.enabled = NO;
```

Hope this helps... :)

**Edit:**

I think you can use this

```
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Add this:

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled{

if (!enabled) {
    self.alpha = 0.3;
}else{
    self.alpha = 1.0;
}
[super setEnabled:enabled];
```

}

Comment: I think question is something different. when button is disable it doesn't look like disable(like gray indicate disable).

Comment: @bohanl Ya I understand. Could you show your drawing code?

Comment: @Mani, updated the question to make it less confusing

Comment: @Rashad, shared my code above, `[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];` did not work. I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you share some more details of your implementation. Moreover I am sure you have called

```
Super methods in the customized methods at first call.
```

Comment: good point, I did forget it. But adding `[super drawRect:rect]` didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `setEnabled:` method of your `CustomButton`

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    if (!enabled) {
        [self setAlpha:0.2f];
    }
}
```

**OR**

If you have to change the color of UIButton in its disabled state. Yo can change `drawRect:` method as

Make a `assign` property of `BOOL` type variable (say *isEnabled*)

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(rect);

    if (!self.isEnabled) {
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(rect);
    }
}

-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    self.isEnabled = enabled;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a method which can help u for enable and disable of your button just add this method in custom button class

```
 //in customButton.h file
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  


 @interface CustomButton : UIButton
 @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL faceUp;//your property
 - (void)makeButtonDisable:(BOOL)disable;//method to handle disable and enable
 @end


 //in customButton.m file

 #import "CustomButton.h"
@implementation CustomButton
{
  CALayer *grayLayer;//layer to handle disable and enable
}
@synthesize faceUp;

  //  in initilization method
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
   {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if(self)
     {
      grayLayer = [CALayer layer];
      grayLayer.frame = frame;
      [self.layer addSublayer:grayLayer]; //add the grayLayer during initialisation 
     }
     return self;
   }



//your code that put above
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
  // Drawing code
  if (self.faceUp) {
    [self drawCardText:self.card.contents inRect:self.bounds];
    } else {
    [self drawCardImage:[UIImage imageNamed:CardBackImageName] inRect:self.bounds];
   }
 }

 - (void)drawCardText:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   // set background color to white so text can be shown
   [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
   [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] fill];

   UIFont *preferedFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
   UIFont *actualFont = [UIFont fontWithName:preferedFont.fontName
                                 size:hypotf(rect.size.width, rect.size.height) / 6.0];

   NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: actualFont};

   NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];
   [self setAttributedTitle:attributedText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

 - (void)drawCardImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 1.0f);
   [image drawInRect:rect];
   UIImage *actualImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:actualImage] setFill];
   [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect] fill];
 }

 //add this method 
 - (void)makeButtonDisable:(BOOL)disable
 {
    if(disable)
    {
     grayLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:201.0f/255.0f green:201.0f/255.0f blue:201.0f/255.0f alpha:5.0f].CGColor;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    grayLayer.opacity = 0.5f;
    self.alpha = 0.5f;
   }
   else
   {
    grayLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    grayLayer.opacity = 0.0f;
    self.alpha = 1.0f;
   }

}
```

in the controller where u are using this button

```
   //some where in the controller u want to disable the button just do like this

  //to disable
  [button makeButtonDisable:YES]; //button is an instance of customCell

 //to enable
  [button makeButtonDisable:NO]; //button is an instance of customCell
```